# How can i earn enough reputation to comment?

Tags: support, comments

I often find that i can answer a question partially, can help steer people in the right direction or provide a link with more information. These things however are almost never good enough for a full answer and are better posted as comments.

However, i don't have enough reputation to comment.

Is there any way for someone like me (good enough to help, but not good enough to give large in-dept answers) to earn more reputation so i can comment on questions?

bear in mind that i don't want to go around asking useless questions just to get this number higher.

Comment: Do you have an account on a different stack exchange site, such as super user or stackoverflow? If you create a new account thats linked to that account you automatically get 100 repuation if the parent account has a high enough reputation. Otherwise I think you might be stuck asking and answering questions, but maybe someone else has an alternative.

Comment: You can get 2 rep for an approved edit. But don't abuse that... Also, it appears as though your problem has been solved.

Comment: Yea seems i was a bit impatient. So is editing the only other way to gain rep?

Comment: Other than asking and answering questions, I believe editing is the only way. This is a Q/A site after all. You can also paypal me a good sum of money and I'll put a 500 point bounty on a question you've answered.

Comment: Haha if only i had money to paypal. Well i can now comment on things, so i'm  happy with that.